# Unable to build link to document due to missing title (in index)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, confluence

I am using sphinx for documentation. When I am using "make confluence", I am getting the below warnings from the index.rst file.

How can I remove these warnings? Also, Table of content is not working in confluence due to these warning but the documentation is getting created in the code.

Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciable.

```html
[4px@learning-2 docs]$ make confluence
Running Sphinx v4.2.0
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [confluence]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
/home/4px/sphinx/docs/source/index.rst:: WARNING: unable to build link to document due to missing title (in index): genindex
/home/4px/sphinx/docs/source/index.rst:: WARNING: unable to build link to document due to missing title (in index): py-modindex
/home/4px/sphinx/docs/source/index.rst:: WARNING: unable to build link to document due to missing title (in index): search
publishing documents... [100%] index
Publish point: https://<........>.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/4194009282
building intersphinx... done

build succeeded, 3 warnings.
```

index.rst file-

```html
.. 4px documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Tue Oct 26 11:19:49 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

API Documentation
**************************

CODE DOCUMENTATION
====================================

.. toctree::
      :hidden:

   index



featureSelection
==================
.. automodule:: featureSelection
   :members:


interpolate
============
.. automodule:: interpolate
      :members:

pets
============
.. automodule:: pets
         :members:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I got one github issue regarding this warning, but it was for older version.

[Sphinx 2.2.2 warning · Issue #265 · sphinx-contrib/confluencebuilder](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/confluencebuilder/issues/265)

Comment: Please update your question with the content of your `index.rst` file.

Comment: Just now updated the content of index.rst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below warnings are removed after cleaning up the index.rst file and creating individual rst file for each python script instead of adding structured format in an index.rst as above.

It yields another advantage of creating TOC page in confluence on its own.

The structure of index.rst should be below in cd docs/sources directory, where assets, plant,Site, pipeline are the name of the python script

index.rst-

```html
.. spectRRa documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Apr 24 11:55:57 2020.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

**API Docs**
***************
.. toctree::
   assets
   plants
   pipelines
   sites
```

Also create all individual rst file in cd docs/sources/ directory.

Ex-For assets.py script,the assets.rst file will be below.

assets.rst-

```html
.. spectRRa documentation master file, created by
 sphinx-quickstart on Fri Apr 24 11:55:57 2020.
 You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
 contain the root `toctree` directive.

 .. toctree::
       :maxdepth: 2
       :caption: Contents:

**Assets**
=================

.. automodule:: assets
    :members:
```

Note-Pls don't change indentation otherwise, it won't work and throw indentation warnnings.

Ref Link-[Stack overflow TOC page generation in confluence using sphinx confluence builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897030/how-to-build-multiple-pages-in-confluence-using-sphinx-documentation)

[Sphinx Documentation](https://github.com/Shravankumarhiregoudar/sphinxDocumentation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but your reStructuredText has random indentation and mismatched heading underline lengths. White space matters in reStructuredText. Try cleaning it up, like so:

```
API Documentation
*****************

CODE DOCUMENTATION
==================

.. toctree::
    :hidden:

    index


featureSelection
================
.. automodule:: featureSelection
    :members:


interpolate
===========
.. automodule:: interpolate
    :members:


pets
====
.. automodule:: pets
    :members:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Comment: I correct the indentation, but still getting the error's.I guess confluence don't support building TOC using sphinx.I will try to build Table of content manually.

After removing Indices and tables, the warning is not coming.

Thanks, Steve for your support.

****************************************
Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`

Answer (score 0):

You are building a confluence page which doesn't support these.  If you try `make html` you'll notice you don't have these warnings because sphinx creates search pages and indices pages for you.  Confluence already has these capabilities built in. (It is a little strange to create an 'index page' in confluence.) Either way, your `:ref:` lines are not necessary when you are building confluence. If you are building both confluence and html just ignore the warning. If you still really want index pages in confluence (not sure how you can duplicate search), you can try and build the pages manually without your `:ref:` lines.